# ripgrep not getting all occurrences in huge file

Tags: search, grep

I'm trying to get all occurrences in huge file (37GB).
But it gives me not all results. How to fix it in ripgrep search?

```
rg "drive" file_name.txt -c
5673

// to compare:
sift "drive" file_name.txt -c
342894

grep "drive" file_name.txt -c
342894
```

**UPDATE**

MacOS

Comment: what's your OS? have you tried a regular GNU grep?

Comment: this can relate to some `ripgrep` limitations, I suppose (может связано с тем, что `ripgrep` не поддерживает многострочный поиск, но это только предположение)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, as I understand, u are right :( the_silver_searcher has problems with big files too - github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/issues/1038 So, sift is the best for today )

Comment: There are no "ripgrep limitations" that would cause this. Please file a bug on the ripgrep issue tracker and please include enough information for others to reproduce. i.e., Find a smaller file to search that causes the same consistency. If you don't give enough info to reproduce your problem, then nobody can answer your question.

Comment: ripgrep does not have the same problems with big files as the silver searcher.

Comment: @BurntSushi5, done - https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/474

Answer (score 0):

It was possible to get correct result with --mmap

```
rg 'drive' file_name.txt -c --no-mmap
5673
rg 'drive' file_name.txt -c --mmap
342894
```

But it took 165 sec (when sift did it in 57 sec) on macbook pro 8GB

**UPDATE**

The reason was in `<NUL>` in text. In that case `rg 123 -c file_name.txt` stop working further and return nothing. `grep` return 3. This file you can get [there](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9sqgidcdr7dru9/file_name.txt?dl=0)
[image]

**UPDATE**

Because of `<NUL>` the file was detected like binary. So `rg -a ...` fixed the problem.
And now it is faster (45 sec) and sift with the same `-a` is very close (48 sec).
Thanks to @BurntSushi5 for ripgrep!

Comment: Note that you're searching a file that doesn't fit in RAM, so the timings you've reported here are probably misleading. For example, if you ran sift after you ran ripgrep, then part of the file might already be in memory, which would make the sift search faster. There are other things that can realistically influence time at this scale, for example, if something else is using up your disk bandwidth then that will also cause times to fluctuate.

Comment: @BurntSushi5, sift I used (and speed was the same) with that file many times before I've installed ripgrep.

Comment: Right, but if something else was using up disk bandwidth (or if your file cache changed), then that could cause the particular ripgrep execution to slow. The idea the `-a` made ripgrep faster supports the idea that you benchmarks are... strange to say to least.

Comment: Finally, note that if you remove the `-c` flag, then grep and sift will simply report that the "binary file matches."

Comment: I call rg and sift for the same file many times (~50 times in different time of the day with different apps running) on the same ssd and the results always very close (45-48 sec.) with `-a`. Just my experience, not a pro benchmarking :)

Comment: Removing the `-c` flag for sift gives msg that the "Binary file matches..." for that small test file that I created, and it is good. And for the huge file with `<NUL>` it worked without any message and gave correct result, and it is good too. And with `-c` it gave correct result too. rg worked at another way in that cases ... - with `-c` - no msg, just nothing or wrong result. It was good that I checked rg result with another command. So with text files it seems always better for rg to use `-a`. In opposite way it can (depends on luck) give wrong result to the user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143547/discussion-between-sviatoslav-and-burntsushi5).